# Get minutes between me and a pin xamarin forms

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use Xamarin.Forms.Googlemaps.

I've been googling for a while now but cant find a good solution. I use James GeoLocator Nuget to get my position. I also have several pins on the map.

So I would like to get the "distance" in minutes (riding in a car) between my position and the pin. It this achievable?

Thanks

Comment: You certainly can get the miles/km via the Google directions API and expand the  Encoded Polylines that are returned, whether you can convert that to minutes (MPH/KPH) is up to your understanding of the traffic flow along that route...

Comment: Ok, so you are saying that I need to manually calculate the speed limit on all roads? @SushiHangover

Comment: Basically yes... if you look at an app like Google's Waze, they built an entire traffic model and related infrastructure based on realtime reporting, AI modeling traffic flow, detailed GIS mapping that includes turn restrictions, speed profiles, traffic lights, left hand turn times, etc... Google directions API includes turn by turn navigation details, but only in miles/km, not time (as in this case it would directly complete with their own Waze app). There are 3rd-party mapping/traffic services that provide things like ETA estimations, just google/bing it (companies like Mapbox, Here, ....)

Comment: It really depends upon the type of service you are trying to provide your app's users and the type of ETA that you would need to provide them... maybe their current speed divided by the number of miles to go is "good enough", but only you an answer that.